# Как вывести все дочерние категории в header.tpl?

Tags: opencart

есть структура такая

Каталог -> И категории что идут дочерние, вложенные и.т.п

При выводе $categories у меня показываются лишь дочерние для 1 уровня( т.е для каталога) А дочерние для текущих дочерних - нет. Каким образом можно исправить и вывести дочерние для дочерних каталога( 3 уровень )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из коробки `opencart` никогда не поддерживал вложенность категорий > 2. Т.е. в админке можно задавать вложенность на сколько фантазии хватит, но программно на фронте это не обеспечено. А возможность задать в админке любу вложенность - это фактически баг, вытекающий из контструктивной осбенности бизнес-логики :)

Выхода два - напильник, кувалда, терпение и пилить (можно и без терпения, ибо пилить там особо нефиг). Либо искать готовый модуль, модифицирующий отображение меню категорий (ну и модуля `меню`, который в расширениях).

ЗюЫю Кстати я лично считаю хорошей практикой проектирование структуры магазина с вложенностью категорий <= 2.